# FlowListView Not Updating Ui with Obeservable

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I can't seem to get my Flowlist to Update With a Timed Method and A Observable Collection

So I start with the Timer

```
 protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            MakeWebRequest();
            if (IsConnected)
            {//10 Seconds for Testing
                Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () =>
                {
                    Task.Run(async () =>
                    {//This does Fire everytime
                      await InitAsync();
                    });
                    return true;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new ErrorView());
            }
        }
```

Here's the List

```
 public class Flashlist : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Product> _items;



        public Flashlist(List<Product> itemList)
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
            if (itemList == null) return;
            foreach (var itm in itemList)
                Items.Add(itm);

        }

        public ObservableCollection<Product> Items
        {
            get => _items;
            private set
            {
                _items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Items");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

The Method should make a API call Then Set the Listview

```
   private async Task InitAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var rest = new RestAPI("http://Site/wp-json/wc/v3/",
                    "xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx");
                var wc = new WCObject(rest);

                var product = await wc.Product.GetAll(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"tag", "1486"},
                    {"per_page", "80"}
                });

                if (product != null)
                {
                    _items = new Flashlist(product);
                }
                else
                { 
                    _items.Items.Clear();
                }  
                  productsListView.FlowItemsSource = _items.Items.Where(z => z.status == "publish").ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
                Analytics.TrackEvent(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

The list Updates fine If I go Remove/Add Products on the Backend
But the UI just remains Still The Product either stays Or it doesn't ever show up I have the same Implementation on other Views and it works fine,This is the only page with a timer So i'm curious if anyone has some idea's?

Comment: This is because you are not `await`ing your `Task.Run(...)` call. Task.Run will return immediately and the runtime will continue on, unless you await it

Comment: @MindSwipe If I await the Task.Run I have to make the Lambda Async Which in turn I get ```Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type 'Func<bool>'. An async lambda expression may return void, Task or Task<T>, none of which are convertible to 'Func<bool>'.```

Comment: Here is my running GIF https://imgur.com/a/C13C6H4 , I used static data in the `OnAppearing` method. I warp the add data method used `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()`, You can use `Task.Result` in an Async Method to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
  productsListView.FlowItemsSource = _items.Items.Where(z => z.status == "publish").ToList();
});
```

It will force it to update on the main thread.